Dynamic Column Mapping in Talend
Want to read the csv file that has different number of columns every day
Problem: I have a 4 to 5 csv files that come in daily all of them have the same purpose. They are generated by a logger. Now I the problem am facing is that I noticed that all of the csv files just have different number of columns every day. Like for example one day the loggers generated files with 31 columns and the very next day 37. Though I did noticed a pattern that first 12 columns and the last 5 columns of every file are consistent but in between those are not. So being a python nerd I was hey this'll be easy to implement I can do that, foolish me.
I really need any help you can provide that'll mean a lot
Here are some of the constraints:
I have to use talend for this sadly can't change that . Can't install more dependencies or libraries cause my company says too much to manage further down the road
So far what I have tried:
Used tInputFileDelimited to map the cols but as they are dynamic from source you can't set the schema
Used a single col in the inputFile schema to get all the cols in one dynamic cols but it didn't included any headers
